# TFS\Team Services, Using Azure KeyVault secrets from a Variable Group in a Build Definition

Tags: azure, tfs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have a simple Build setup in Team Services. The build simply downloads source code from a Team Services hosted Git repo and then executes a Powershell script.

The Powershell Script receives 4 parameters;

```
-SiteName "$(AppServiceName)" -AzureRMTenantID "$(AzureRMTenantID)" -AzureRMUN "$(AzureRMUN)" -AzureRMPW "$(AzureRMPW)"
```

AppServiceName is entered manually when the build is queued.

The 3 AzureRM* parameters should be coming from a Variable Group which I have linked to the Build Definition;

[image: variable configuration within the Build Job]
The Variable Group **AzureDevOps** is configured to Link the Secrets from Azure Key Vault as variables;

[image: Variable Group configured in the Library]

Based on everything I have been able to find regarding this pattern, it seems like it should just work.

As an interim sanity check, I am printing the variables out in my powershell script just so I can confirm they are being passed correctly.

Thus far, I have not been able to get the values of any of the AzureRM* variables to print correctly which leads me to believe they are **NOT** being passed as expected.

```
Generating script.
Formatted command: . 'd:\a\1\s\AppServices\Create Canned App Service Application.ps1' -SiteName "Testers" -AzureRMTenantID "" -AzureRMUN "" -AzureRMPW ""
"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoLogo -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File "d:\a\_temp\23b9a27a-4b6d-4232-8e24-150173e08915.ps1"
Working Set of Variables:
SiteName:  Testers
ResourceGroup: Applications
ASE Name: appservices-ase
Location: East US
Additional Variables:
AzureRMTenantID:
```

I am not expecting the variables to be printed in the log command here;

```
Formatted command: . 'd:\a\1\s\AppServices\Create Canned App Service Application.ps1' -SiteName "Testers" -AzureRMTenantID "" -AzureRMUN "" -AzureRMPW ""
```

but I would expect them to be printed within my script where I am explicitly writing them out;

```
Write-Host "Working Set of Variables:`nSiteName: "$SiteName"`r`nResourceGroup: "$RG"`r`nASE Name: "$ASEName"`r`nLocation: "$Location
Write-Host "Additional Variables:`nAzureRMTenantID: "$AzureRMTenantID"`r`n"$AzureRMUN"`r`n"$AzureRMPW
```

If I run the PS script locally, the values do print as expected;

```
PS C:\ashley\scm\AzureAutomation\AppServices> & '.\Create Canned App Service Application.ps1' -SiteName "tester" -AzureRMTenantID 12345 -AzureRMUN user -AzureRMPW 1234
Working Set of Variables:
SiteName:  tester
ResourceGroup: Applications
ASE Name: appservices-ase
Location: East US
Additional Variables:
AzureRMTenantID:  12345
user
1234
```

Does anyone know how to make this work? I am wondering if the problem has to do with the KeyVault permissions since the request is coming from the "Hosted 2017" Agent Queue built into Team Services.

Answer (score 2):

First, you can’t print out the secret variables’ value, you can send the data to a service (e.g. Web API) to get the actual data during the build/release.

Secondly, the Key Vault secrets variables are used for release, it will add Azure Key Vault task during the release. [Link secrets from an Azure Key vault as variables](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/concepts/library/variable-groups#link-secrets-from-an-azure-key-vault-as-variables)

You will get the empty value if you are using in build. You can add [Key Vault Task](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/tree/master/Tasks/AzureKeyVault) to the build definition, then you can use the related variables in the following tasks. (Do not need to link to that variable group in build definition)

Comment: Thanks starain-MSFT, I'll try building this as a release today and see if it helps. Are there any plans to support this in a Build Definition in the future?

Comment: @Sage No official article mentions it, but you can submit the user voice [here](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/category/145254-ci-build). On the other hand, does my reply/answer solves your original issue?

Comment: @starianchen-MSFT this should be documented in the VSTS site, please make sure the documentation is updated.

Comment: @starianchen-MSFT actually just checking the documentation, it says it should work with builds as well? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-key-vault?view=vsts

Comment: Hi @starianchen-MSFT am working the on the samer concept, here am i can able to fetch the secrets from KeyVault. But, am getting them in *** format. So that, i can't able to use them for further tasks. What is the problem for it

Answer (score 0):

The Key Vault support currently works only with Release Definitions. You can create a Release Definition and link your Git Repo as an artifact and can achieve the same.

I receive this error while linking Azure Keyvault VG to BD.[image]

Comment: interesting, I didnt get any kind of error like that in all my dorking around. Had I, I probably wouldnt have ended up posting this question. Was this error shown in the web portal or somewhere else?

Comment: @Sage I think we have recently started showing errors and those changes may not have reached your account till now. You can add KeyVault task as pointed out by starain-MSFT

Comment: Hi @Harshil, still no error message when linking to a build definition. No worries though, I understand the point about KeyVault backed Variable Groups not working in Build Definitions. This is something we are able to work around in our environment.

I was looking to reuse PS scripts from our Jenkins to perform the same work in Release Management. In the end, I opted to comment out the AzureRMLogin process (which needs these variables) and use the built in Powershell on Azure Task to complete the work.